# Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection Some

Tags: r

```
  ## this script assumes that it is started in the working directory
tracker_directory<-normalizePath(getwd())

# setting parameters ------------------------------------------------------


# additional R configuration ----------------------------------------------

# load packages
library(magrittr)

setwd(dirname(getwd()))

# load helper functions
source("R/max_departure.r")

# run methodologies -------------------------------------------------------
```

**Here I have the R file which is referencing to other R file**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Mm3.png

Answer (score 0):

Note that `dirname(getwd())` returns the parent directory of your current working directory. Maybe that is the issue? If `getwd()` returns the directory that contains *main.R* there is no need for the `setwd()` call, I think.

Comment: Without setwd() also its not working. Giving me the same error. In the image I have the folder structure.

Comment: Do you have a file called `"max_departure.r"` in the `"R"` folder? The error indicates there is a problem opening the specified file path. Also, from the information you have provided we can't tell whether this is some other file connection problem related to whatever code is being sourced from max_departure.r

Comment: Yes the file is there